# Red5 Streaming dynamic Content

Tags: java, flash, streaming, flv, red5

I'm getting my feet wet with red5 and am trying to make a basic app that will stream a random video to the client.

Let's say I have 3 flvs on my server, I'd like a client to connect to my red5 app and have 1 of these 3 videos streamed to them. The only streaming i've been able to figure out so far uses `netStream.play("video.flv")`, this doesn't work for me, I wan't the server to decide on the file to stream rather than the client, any help is really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We've made a first-pass at supporting dynamic streaming and you can read my post about it here: http://gregoire.org/2011/07/19/dynamic-streaming-with-red5/